# Hosting ASP.net website through coding in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

We already have some .aspx pages that comprise a website. We can browse these pages in the browser once we host that website in IIS. But now our requirement is to host these pages in the standalone C# application. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> You can create custom browser in your `C#` application using below links

You can try this.

- [Link for create browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12029/Automate-the-Active-Windows-Explorer-or-Internet-E)
- [another link for create browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and)

Comment: @Deepali Dhumal - If answer is useful, Please click on 'correct' and give 'upvote' so it will helps other to find out correct solution.